# Difference between CLOSE and CLOSE_FRACTION

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost-test

Can anybody explain the difference between **BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE** and **BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION**?

I just skimmed through the boost.test Testing Tools Reference and I'm pretty sure that they have an equal description.

Comment: Yes, definitely a duplicate

Comment: And really answered. Ok, this one can be closed.